# Is there a way I can use two classes or more for one Activity in android studio?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way I can use two classes or more for one Activity in android studio?
I used this Test code but this App crashes:

Note : This is  for learning  purposes so that it can be used to split up huge classes into sub classes
//Main Activity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Test ob=new Test ();
  ob.test();
}
```

}

//  Test Class

```
public class Test extends MainActivity {
public void test()
{
    TextView t=findViewById(R.id.h);
    t.setText("Miaooo");
}
```

}

Comment: Well, it keeps telling me that there is an attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference .

Comment: I'd suggest to just make helper methods on your activity class if the only issue is the "hugeness" of your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to pass the activity with as the parameter of constructor and use that reference to call "findViewbyId()"

```
public class Test{
public void test(Activity activity)
{
    TextView t=activity.findViewById(R.id.h);
    t.setText("Miaooo");
}
```

while in your main activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Test ob=new Test (this);
  ob.test();
}
```

If you want to your "Test" class to be extended by an activity than you should use activity creation wizard to setup all the stuff in manifest and .xml. It would be quite long process to do it manually.

Comment: Thank you so much , My MainActivity  Class is becoming huge so all I need now is to spill it up into other subclasses or into anything just to make it readable and easy to maintain later .. I really started hating programming .lol

Answer (score 0):

When you write `class Test extends MainActivity` it means that `Test` should be activity too and you have to write `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);` to set the view layer for your activity. Also, `Test` should be registered as Activity in your manifest file. Anyway if you want to change the text of the TextView why you want to create a new activity?

place your code in the activity main.

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    test();
}

public void test()
{
    TextView t=findViewById(R.id.h);
    t.setText("Miaooo");
}
```

Comment: if you want to change the text of the TextView why you want to create a new activity? Well , this just is for learning purposes .. I wrote an app that contains more than 1500 line in just one class , so it became hard to maintain and I want to split those Methods into other classes